# Ajax request not working in loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, strongloop, loopback

I am beginner in loopback and working on Get Post in loopback
This is code on client side

```
var datas = 'Something';    
 $.ajax({   
      type: 'POST',   
      url: '/post',  
      data: datas,  
      dataType: 'text'  
       })  
         .done(function(data) {  
            console.log('Successful');  
         .fail(function(jqXhr) {  
            console.log('Failed');
```

});

and this is on server side(server.js)

```
app.post('/post', function(req, res){  


 console.log('This is DATA '+ req.body);
```

});

This is not working it gives me 404 not found or failed.
What am I doing wrong and Is there another method for get post in loopback?

Comment: your url might be not correct, check it once

Comment: I have checked it with '/' and also with http://localhost:3000/post on client side and '/post' on server side.

Comment: it must contain something like localhost:port/controller/action. Here post is action not controller, so you are getting 404.

Answer (score 0):

the server side needs an server and listening a port.

the client side needs to listen another port.

so they are not in one domain and cannot get access to each other.

this called a "cross-origin requests"

check this for the solution:https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

Answer (score 0):

Your URL starts with '/'.
Whenever a URL starts with '/' it is treated as absolute URL.

Whereas, most of the time, web apps are bounded with a context root.
Try using URL without initial '/' and it should work.

Comment: Are you sure you have configured express in right way ? 
app.use( '/', route );
Something like this ?

Comment: I am using loopback.